# DataObject.PutInClipboard raises error "Not Implemented"

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, clipboard

I'm attempting to use the MsForms DataObject to preserve the contents of the windows Clipboard during VBA code operations which use Copy/Paste methods of the Range object.
Unfortunately an error is raised whenever I copy plain text (e.g. from Notepad or from the VB IDE etc). The error occurs when DataObject.PutInClipboard is called.
Note that this error does NOT occur when an excel cell or range is copied. I have made some example code to demonstrate the error.

To use the code, paste it in a standard VBA code module. Then copy some text (e.g. from the Immediate Window etc). Then run the macro `TestClipboard`. You should get the error on the indicated line.

You will note that the routine `ShowClipboardFormats` shows that when plain text is copied, the clipboard contains the formats 0 (Text) and 44 (Unknown). When a cell is copied, the clipboard contains these (0 and 44) along with several other formats. So it isn't as if the DataObject is encountering a format it can't handle, because the plain text formats are a subset of the cell formats.

I am currently using Office 2013 64-bit on Windows 8.1. I guess it is possible that this is a 64-bit issue, and I will test the code on a 32-bit machine when I get the chance. I've seen reports of this problem elsewhere, but no solution yet. In most cases people misunderstood the problem. (e.g. they thought the cliboard was empty or contained invalid data etc. This is NOT the case).

```vb
Public Sub TestClipboard()
    Dim oData As DataObject
    Set oData = New DataObject
    ShowClipboardFormats
    oData.GetFromClipboard
    oData.PutInClipboard 'Error occurs here, but only when plain text is selected
End Sub

Public Sub ShowClipboardFormats()
    Dim I&, nFmt&
    Debug.Print "Formats on Clipboard: "
    For I = 1 To UBound(Application.ClipboardFormats)
        nFmt = Application.ClipboardFormats(I)
        Debug.Print nFmt, GetNameOfFormat(nFmt)
    Next I
End Sub

Public Function GetNameOfFormat$(nFormat As XlClipboardFormat)
    Dim S$
    Select Case nFormat
        Case xlClipboardFormatBIFF: S = "BIFF" '8 = Binary Interchange file format for Excel version 2.x
        Case xlClipboardFormatBIFF12:   S = "BIFF12" '63 = Binary Interchange file format 12
        Case xlClipboardFormatBIFF2:    S = "BIFF2" '18 = Binary Interchange file format 2
        Case xlClipboardFormatBIFF3:    S = "BIFF3" '20 = Binary Interchange file format 3
        Case xlClipboardFormatBIFF4:    S = "BIFF4" '30 = Binary Interchange file format 4
        Case xlClipboardFormatBinary:   S = "Binary" '15 = Binary format
        Case xlClipboardFormatBitmap:   S = "Bitmap" '9 = Bitmap format
        Case xlClipboardFormatCGM:  S = "CGM" '13 = CGM format
        Case xlClipboardFormatCSV:  S = "CSV" '5 = CSV format
        Case xlClipboardFormatDIF:  S = "DIF" '4 = DIF format
        Case xlClipboardFormatDspText:  S = "DspText" '12 = Dsp Text format
        Case xlClipboardFormatEmbeddedObject:   S = "EmbeddedObject" '21 = Embedded Object
        Case xlClipboardFormatEmbedSource:  S = "EmbedSource" '22 = Embedded Source
        Case xlClipboardFormatLink: S = "Link" '11 = Link
        Case xlClipboardFormatLinkSource:   S = "LinkSource" '23 = Link to the source file
        Case xlClipboardFormatLinkSourceDesc:   S = "LinkSourceDesc" '32 = Link to the source description
        Case xlClipboardFormatMovie:    S = "Movie" '24 = Movie
        Case xlClipboardFormatNative:   S = "Native" '14 = Native
        Case xlClipboardFormatObjectDesc:   S = "ObjectDesc" '31 = Object description
        Case xlClipboardFormatObjectLink:   S = "ObjectLink" '19 = Object link
        Case xlClipboardFormatOwnerLink:    S = "OwnerLink" '17 = Link to the owner
        Case xlClipboardFormatPICT: S = "PICT" '2 = Picture
        Case xlClipboardFormatPrintPICT:    S = "PrintPICT" '3 = Print picture
        Case xlClipboardFormatRTF:  S = "RTF" '7 = RTF format
        Case xlClipboardFormatScreenPICT:   S = "ScreenPICT" '29 = Screen Picture
        Case xlClipboardFormatStandardFont: S = "StandardFont" '28 = Standard Font
        Case xlClipboardFormatStandardScale:    S = "StandardScale" '27 = Standard Scale
        Case xlClipboardFormatSYLK: S = "SYLK" '6 = SYLK
        Case xlClipboardFormatTable:    S = "Table" '16 = Table
        Case xlClipboardFormatText: S = "Text" '0 = Text
        Case xlClipboardFormatToolFace: S = "ToolFace" '25 = Tool Face
        Case xlClipboardFormatToolFacePICT: S = "ToolFacePICT" '26 = Tool Face Picture
        Case xlClipboardFormatVALU: S = "VALU" '1 = Value
        Case xlClipboardFormatWK1:  S = "WK1" '10 = Workbook
        Case Else: S = "Unknown"
    End Select
    GetNameOfFormat = S
End Function
```

Of course the error itself can be ignored by using `on error resume next` etc, but the issue is that I want to be able to restore the contents of the clipboard. I suppose the best work-around would be something like this:

```vb
Public Sub StoreClipboard()
    'm_StoredData is defined at module level:
    '  Private m_StoredData As MSForms.DataObject

    Set m_StoredData = New DataObject
    With m_StoredData
        .GetFromClipboard
        If .GetFormat(1) Then Debug.Print "Stored Clipboard Text: " & m_StoredData.GetText(1)
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub RestoreClipboard()
    If m_StoredData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim sText$
    With m_StoredData
        If .GetFormat(1) Then
            sText = .GetText(1)
            Debug.Print "Stored Text: " & sText
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        .PutInClipboard
        Debug.Print "Has Text After: " & .GetFormat(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Had Error"
            If sText <> "" Then
                .SetText sText, 1
                .PutInClipboard
                Debug.Print "Restored Text: " & sText
            End If
        End If
        Set m_StoredData = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

But as I've been testing that code, something else strange seems to be happening. First, note that `.PutInClipboard` when it causes the error also causes the stored text to be lost. (i.e. it prints "Has Text After: False")
Secondly and even more concerning, if I change the clipboard contents between the call to `StoreClipboard` and `RestoreClipboard`, (e.g. I copy "Pizza", then call `StoreClipboard`, then copy "Orange") then `RestoreClipboard` prints "Stored Text: Orange" (i.e. new NEW contents). But how is that possible? The DataObject should only have "Pizza" stored on it. The call to `GetText` seems to be updating from the clipboard, not from the content stored in the dataobject. Strange. 
Can anyone confirm these findings and/or explain them?

Thanks!

Comment: I can also reproduce the behaviour you mentioned at the start with plain text. For a test, I added `oData.SetText oData.GetText` (in one line) between the `GetFromClipboard` and `PutInClipboard` lines in your code and that worked in both cases (selected plain text and selected a cell/range of cells from the sheet).

Comment: Thanks djikay. Am I right in assuming that when you copy a Range and use that line of code (`oData.SetText oData.GetText`), you lose any cell formatting (and other clipboard formats) associated with the Range?

Comment: Yes, with that *particular* line you would lose the format. **But** you can specify the format as an (optional) parameter to both `GetText` and `SetText`.

Comment: You are right, but there is no way (that I'm aware of) to enumerate the formats stored in the dataobject. So given arbitrary contents on the clipboard, there is not a way to safely store it and then restore it at a later time. Right?

Comment: Well, you're stretching my understanding of `DataObject`. What you say sounds right, I couldn't find a way to do that myself, but I'm not overly familiar with this object.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I submitted a report to microsoft to see if they can help. I assume they won't be able to help. It appears the DataObject simply cannot be used to backup and restore the full clipboard state--only the text. And actually, I've found that it can't even put text onto the clipboard, so the point is moot. I've discussed this latter problem here: http://tinyurl.com/dataobject

Comment: I have definitely managed to put text onto the clipboard. I just called `SetText` first and then `PutInClipboard` and that has generally worked for me. But MS should at least give you some advice and hopefully a solution. Good luck!

Comment: You're right about SetText. I was having reproducible trouble with it, but I restarted my computer and now it is working. I think my clipboard must have just been corrupated by all the DataObject testing I was doing.